# Is there an easy way to create a string from a string array in C?

Tags: c, string

I am talking about some sort of function that can combine an array of character arrays into a single string.

Would I just have to loop through the array of strings and do it manually? The string was created using strtok().

Comment: One might say there is *no* easy way to work with strings in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using standard C and the standard C library, you have to loop through and do it manually.  (Of course you might use `strncat` in your loop.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of `char` arrays, like this:

```
char foo[<num>][<len>];
```

...then you can convert it into a string like this:

```
char *bar = (char *)foo;
```

If your strings are `NULL`-terminated or smaller than `len`, you may have to `memmove()` `foo[i+1]` to the position of `strlen(bar)` for each `i`.

Of course, it might be easier to just iterate through the array and concatenate the strings using `strcat()`.